# undefined method `assert_equal' for #<Object:0x007fda5fe47780> (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby, rest, api, authentication, cucumber

I am getting the following message
`undefined method 'assert_equal' for #<Object:0x007fda5fe47780> (NoMethodError)`

I have added all the relevant gems but still getting the same error. Please see attached link to github repo [enter link description here](https://github.com/shafiqahmedmalik2010/api_excercise)

Any suggestions?

Comment: https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Using-MiniTest

Comment: Could you please paste your code that seems to be causing this error? I believe its `"api_excercise/features/step_definitions/user_id.rb"` but I am unsure without some further explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Add `include Test::Unit::Assertions` before using the method `assert_equal`.

Usually you would create a test class that would be a subclass of `Test::Unit::TestCase`, but this should work for your simple test.